# XML data not displaying with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, xhtml

I am currently working on a project, and the idea is an AJAX online shop.
I've created an XML file with two products for an example, and i try to display the makes in a side menu using Javascript. This is my XML:

```
<root>
<car>
    <make>BMW</make>
    <model>1 series</model>
    <color>white</color>
    <image>images/0001.jpg</image>
</car>
<car>
    <make>Mercedes-Benz</make>
    <model>C63</model>
    <color>white</color>
    <image>images/0002.jpg</image>
</car>
</root>
```

This is the javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var myXML, myNodes;
 var display = [];
  myXML = document.all("carsXML").XMLDocument;

 myNodes = myXML.getElementsByTagName("car");
 for(var i=0;i<myNodes.length;i++) {
  display[i] = myNodes.item(i).firstChild.nodeValue;
  $('ul').append('<li>'+display[i]+'</li>')   }});
```

and this is the html:

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Car World</title>
    <xml id="carsXML" src="xml/cars.xml"></xml>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="head">
        <h1>Car World</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="left">
        <ul>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The idea is to create an li for each car make within the same ul
Nothing is showing however. the ul stays empty.

Comment: XML is in another file or same file...??

Comment: @PrasathK  the xml is in another file

Comment: then you should use XMLhttp request

Answer (score 0):

PrasathK is right.

Your code is also - among other things - Internet Explorer specific (document.all). While that may or may not be an issue in your case, my suggestion is that you change course and take a look at something like [jQuery.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), which is cross browser compatible - apparently you are already using jQuery, so this will make parsing and manipulating your XML data that much less cumbersome, in comparison with parsing the DOM yourself.